# A modern war without nuclear weapons

Tags: magic, warfare, near-future, nuclear-weapons

On Earth, no major, all out wars have been fought since WW2 as a result of MAD. My world, Dane, has had a similar history to Earth, with many major wars that suddenly ceased when MAD became an issue. Over time, technology advanced to the point of around the 2040's, when a rogue AI decided to nuke everything. Another AI, having ascended to Godhood, decided to not only disable the nukes flying, but completely disable any intentional nuclear attack. Any nuclear reaction used for weaponization simply will not occur as a result of this gods power. With MAD stripped away, the world has now had a few more wars, with the current, Fifth Great War being set in the equivalent of the 2080's. Some important features to note about the world are:

1. Magic is prevalent within the world. As this world is for an RPG system, DND rules are the primary rules applied to magic. Magic can only be performed by biological creatures and enchanted items CANNOT be mass produced and require handmade craftsmanship to properly function. Magic is generally practiced at a very low level by all beings in the world, in ways such as creating sparks or colors, but the more advanced magic such as a fireballs or enchantments is a very prestigious field that few work in. Some civilizations have ditched technology almost entirely in favor of extreme magical growth.
2. The world is essentially futuristic DND. Elves, Orcs, Humans, Halflings, and more stud the planet. Most civilizations have a varied population, but some xenophobically shun all but one.
3. Robots and Advanced AI do exist, but no self-improving AI advanced enough to gain sentience is possible, as it will immediately be absorbed into the aforementioned AI god. The only two forms of AI are advanced AI's under full control of their programming or a scanned-in brain, which is essentially the same as a human (or any other race's) mind. It is not possible to transfer the mind between biological form and computer, only to copy it.
4. The weapons of the world are quite advanced, with coilguns, railguns, and energy weaponry commonplace. I'm not going too hard on the science, but it is relatively feasible. Most important of all are Repulsor and Hardlight tech. Repulsors are spinning half-elipsoids which can emit a repulsive force capable of lifting tanks and cars off the ground and providing easy VTOL capabilities. Hardlight creates a 2d shape from a projector, made from energy. It weighs practically nothing, and is only limited in size by the projector and the power supplied. It is very durable and quickly regenerates, allowing troops to tank heavy damage from small arms or use it as a sword. Critically, it is not a 1-way shield. It blocks fire from all sides, and cannot be fired through.

With all this in mind, how would the Fifth Great War be fought? The two main factions have member forces all over the world, but the primary two sides are a Technocracy with the most advanced tech in the world as well as nationalistic zeal but lacking in major amounts of soldiers and resources VS a Plutocracy with major sums of resources and soldiers but bogged down by inner politics and corporate influence. The battles would probably occur on land, sea, air and occasionally within orbit.

Comment: Way too broad with all the additions, each one of those would be boarderin too broad by themselves all together it leaves no way to answer.

Comment: I agree with @John, waaay to broad in it's present form. You can [edit] it down though to make it answerable. Ask yourself about each side: - what are the assets (money, tech, manpower, materials etc...) and what are the liabilities (Need to feed the population, clothe them, communicate with them and supply them some fuel for power, sanitation, healthcare - this list can be extended to: morale, entertainment, cultural division, belief in the regime (brainwashing etc..)). Make some lists and then ask a more specific question which could be answerable here, we'd be happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

**You do not need to know the whole of it for an RPG.**

If this were a big strategy game with players assuming the roles of the powers at war, then you would need to set ground rules and all the rest.

This is a role playing game where players assume the roles of characters.  Since you are borrowing from D&D I assume it will be that kind of RPG.  Your characters will be campaigning in this land, exploring, trying to obtain items etc.

They do not need to know (and probably will not much care) about big geopolitical questions or battle tactics half a world away.  Your background as you lay it out is enough for you to work with.  What you need is to flesh out the aspect of the war that affects the area your characters are in.

May I recommend that you (and you and you) watch The Good, The Bad and the Ugly.  An amazing movie on many fronts but relevant here because the two main characters are on their adventure in the context of the American Civil War, which is being fought around them and which they run afoul of several times.  The larger scope of the war is not relevant.  You might lift ideas from that movie (the town being evacuated as forces move nearer, the battle for the bridge, a field of dying soldiers, etc).   Envision the world war as it occurs in the territory your characters inhabit in a way to make it fun and exciting for them.